# Uncapacitated facility location problem with at most k facilities and budget b

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I am trying to solve an uncapacitated facility location problem in which I would like to find the location to open at most k facilities, and assign n clients to those facilities, each with cost c_i (proportionate to the distance of the client from the facility it's assigned to) for assignment with a budget B. So I would like to find the locations of the facilities, and assign clients to those facilities such that the maximum number of clients are serviced within the budget B. I haven't found a variant like this in which there is an overall budget; I've only seen versions where we want to minimize the overall cost while assigning all the clients to facilities.

Comment: This has a strongly NP-complete smell about it.

Comment: If you have a number of possible locations for the facilities, such a problem can typically be formulated as a linear MIP model. If facilities can be placed anywhere on the x-y plane, we typically end up with a quadratic model. [Here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/01/solving-facility-location-problem-as.html) is a similar problem, solved with a MIQCP (Mixed Integer Quadratically Constrained Programming) solver. Of course, you can also apply some heuristic to solve this.